# How Can I Create Calendar Events Programatically With ,Office 365 Calendar Apis

Tags: azure, office365

I am working on a requirement,to create a windows service which send the calendar invites to scheduled meetings from the admin email address for which mail server is hosted on office365. I have created a Azure app and able to get access token, and when I tried to read the calendar  events form the rest service,a Internal sever exception happed".
Follwing is the code snippet I tried.Can you please help me/refer me to the resources ,for acheiving my requirement.

```
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];

    static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);


    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
    private static ClientCredential clientCredential = null;

    public static void CalendarAPICall()
    {
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        int retryCount = 0;
        bool retry = false;
        string header = "";

        do
        {
            retry = false;
            try
            {
                // ADAL includes an in memory cache, so this call will only send a message to the server if the cached token is expired.
                result = authContext.AcquireToken(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
                header = result.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == "temporarily_unavailable")
                {
                    retry = true;
                    retryCount++;
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(
                    String.Format("An error occurred while acquiring a token\nTime: {0}\nError: {1}\nRetry: {2}\n",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                    ex.ToString(),
                    retry.ToString()));
            }

        } while ((retry == true) && (retryCount < 3));

        if (result == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canceling attempt to contact To Do list service.\n");
            return;
        }



        var url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2./me/calendarview?startDateTime=2014-10-01T01:00:00Z&endDateTime=2015-12-31T23:00:00Z";
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var oAuthHeader = header;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);
        var response = request.GetResponse();






    }
```

Comment: You mean the REST call is failing? What is the status code of the failing request, can you read the error message?

Comment: The error message is "500 Internal server error"..Following is the update code snippet for the Rest service request which I am using     ..I tried adding the headers ..but same result....                                        var oAuthHeader = header;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);
            request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
            var newguid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); ;
            request.Headers.Add("client-request-id", newguid);
            request.Date = System.DateTime.Now;

Comment: Ok but the 500 "internal server error" is raised by your server when you use your application or is it the response from the Outlook API REST call? The outlook API should not return a 500 code.

Comment: The `v2.` in the url looks suspicious to me I would try to use `v2.0` instead

Comment: I have actually usede v2.0..I got the same exception